# Android elseif else won't process correctly

Tags: java, android

extreme noob here, i'm trying to export statements not strings within my if else statement. some how it's not working, please help.

```
        if(number==0) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(123, 214, 217)); } 
    elseif(number==1) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(121, 214, 217)); } 
    else {  canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(54, 214, 217));  }
```

Comment: else if (condition) {
       
      }

Comment: You can tell the difference between 121 and 123 units of red? I'm impressed :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo eagle eye vision :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, the syntax is `else if`, not `elseif`.

Comment: wow, eclipse should have this in their error box for unforunate's like me :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
if(number==0) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(123, 214, 217)); } 
    elseif(number==1) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(121, 214, 217)); } 
    else {  canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(54, 214, 217));  }
```

with this:

```
if(number==0) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(123, 214, 217)); } 
    else if(number==1) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(121, 214, 217)); } 
    else {  canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(54, 214, 217));  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 if(number==0) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(123, 214, 217)); } 
    elseif(number==1) { canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(121, 214, 217)); } 
    else {  canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(54, 214, 217));  }
```

with

```
 if(number==0) {
     canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(123, 214, 217));
 } else if(number==1) { 
     canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(121, 214, 217)); 
 } else {  
     canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(54, 214, 217)); 
 }
```

**Always indent your code**. I wonder why, your IDE is not showing you syntax error